# Change Domain Name from localhost to Actual Domain

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I just completed my theme with content development in Xamp (Mac). I am working on WordPress Framework and all theme and content is ready and access using http://localhost/doctorweb/

My actual domain name is doctorweb.co.

Now I want to upload all theme + widgets + content on my actual domain. How is this possible to use all the localhost development change into actual domain name ?

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. Also: there's no need to include your actual domain name. In fact, this can be seen as spam.

Comment: Actually this is not my domain name, i just give example

Answer (score 0):

That config is actually stored on your database when you install/create wordpress database. You can change it manually through mysql console or using phpadmin. It's located on `wp_options` table, you're gonna see two options that defines it: `home` and `siteurl`. Those are the ones you gotta change. Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Glad to read that... please consider givin' an upvote and mark the answer as accepted, once it works =)